# How to put RGBA background above the image or div area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to use RGBA background above this grid. I used some of the jQuery to interect with div area. But I don't know how to put this background-color in image while I'm using jQuery. Is there a way I can do this using jQuery ? or any other methods ?

```js
// Grid function

$(function() {
  $(".single_grid").hover(function() {
    var panelId = $(this).attr("data-panelId");
    $("#" + panelId).css({}).toggle();
  })
  $(".single_grid").mouseover(function() {
    var imageId = $(this).attr("data-imageId");
    $("#" + imageId).css({
      opacity: "0.3"
    })
  })
  $(".single_grid").mouseleave(function() {
    var imageId = $(this).attr("data-imageId");
    $("#" + imageId).css({
      opacity: "1"
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.grid_panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#sub_grid_panel {
  height: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1125px;
}
#sub_grid_panel li {
  float: left;
}
.single_grid {
  width: 280px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.image_hover_preview h3 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'RalewayLight';
  color: #FF8500;
}
.image_hover_preview {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
div.image_hover_preview a i {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #FF8500;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
div.image_hover_preview {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<li class="single_grid" data-panelId="panel1" data-imageId="image1">
  <div class="grid_column_bar">
    <img src="img/grid/grid1.jpg" alt="" id="image1">
    <div class="image_hover_preview" id="panel1">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="single_grid" data-panelId="panel2" data-imageId="image2">
  <div class="grid_column_bar">
    <img src="img/grid/grid2.jpg" alt="" id="image2">
    <div class="image_hover_preview" id="panel2">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

[image: I used Opacity in this image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'm a fan of this little `box-shadow: inset` trick.

Just add a background like you normally would and on top of that,
add a `box-shadow` property like so :

```
.element {
  background-image: url(myBgImage.jpg);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1000px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
}
```

> Note: the spread-radius of 1000px is arbitrarily chosen. Just make sure it exceeds the width/height of your element.

[Box Shadow Generator](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you wanted since your code snippet didn't work at all.

This changes the background color:

```
$(element).css({
    backgroundColor:"rgba(50,50,50,.5)"
});
```

To put the color on top of the background image, you can use gradients:

```
$(element).css({
    backgroundImage:"linear-gradient(rgba(50,50,50,.5),rgba(50,50,50,.5)),url(background.jpg)"
});
```